# Can PyInstaller (or other tools) create an executable file from Django project for production environment?

Tags: django, deployment, pyinstaller

I want to create an executable file from our Django project. Currently we use Daphne as ASGI server hosting both HTTP and web-socket.

I found following link but it seems that PyInstaller is only for Django dev env, not for production.
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django

Am I correct? Is there any other tool allow me to create standalone file for production environment.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you want this.

Comment: I think if is possible, the deployment will be simpler. We don't need to install lots of package on production server.

Comment: But you deal with that problem by using a requirements or pipenv file, not by trying to package up your project as an executable.

Comment: You are right. thanks @DanielRoseman.